# Vaadin MenuItem: do not close when selected

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a submenu inside a `MenuBar`, in which several checkable `MenuItem`s are listed.

By default the menu closes as soon as one item is clicked.

In my use case, the user will typically want to select/deselect several of those items, so I would like to leave the menu open after a selection/click.

Is that somehow possible?

I'm using Vaadin 7.6

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know it's currently not possible. If it's of any use to you as well, I've used the [popup button add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/popupbutton) to achieve a functionality similar to what you're describing, although it's not exactly a menu bar...

Comment: @Morfic Thanks, great hint